# Tracking same domains but different environments in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

So, say I want to track traffic to different environments, but in the same domain

https://portal.mywebsite.net/

and separately track traffic to

https://production.mywebsite.net/

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but do you do this through filters, or do you have to setup new properties per environment? thanks in advance, I'm a noob to GA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create two new views one for portal and one for production:

1. Start with applying a filter to your portal view. Go to View > Filters > Create New Filter
2. Select *Include only* & *traffic to the hostname*, and drop in portal.mywebsite.net.

[image]

Rinse and repeat for production.

Comment: I set these up, just curious though, do those show up in the reports separately as such?

Comment: Yeah, if you've configured them correctly, they should be separate. You can use Real-time reports to check to see if your filters are working correctly.

Comment: thanks - it seems something changed on either my end or within the reports ( not due to this ) and nothing is getting picked up. So, have to debug it. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Cool, if my answer answered your question, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: I have two environments for the same site, but the main domain is different. I understand that both can be tracked separately. But my question is, is there a way we can link this as Production, Staging and development environments?