# Can I grant Google Analytics users access to environment-specific filters/views?

Tags: google-analytics, development-environment

So I'm looking at setting up Google Analytics (GA) for the first time. My app will have three environments (initially):

- Dev
- UAT
- Prod

w.r.t GA I was curious as to whether best practice is to:

- Create 3 distinct GA accounts; 1 for each env; or
- Create 1 GA account and somehow keep the data separate

According to [this accepted + upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808463/4009451), it sounds like the latter is the preferred way of managing GA across environments. And that the solution is to add filters/views to your configurations so that data from each envrironment gets filtered/routed to the correct environment-specific reports.

My only potential problem with this solution is that I need my developers to have access to the dev data in GA, product & QA to have access to the UAT data, and only a handful of key business/marketing folks to have access to the prod data. **Devs should never have access to UAT or Prod data, etc.**

I took a look around GA's permissions documentation and I don't see any way of granting users access to specific filters/views. Anybody have any idea how I could create a "Developer" role inside GA and only grant read access to filters/views/etc *tagged* or marked as being part of the development env?

Otherwise I'll need to sadly create 3 distinct GA accounts, one for each env :-/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My GA setup is very similar to yours.  I have a single GA account that has multiple properties such as web-dev, web-stg, web-prd, mobile-stg, mobile-prod, etc.  Each of those properties have a minimum of two views.  The first view I title 'Raw Data' as no filters should ever be set on this view to have access to the raw data collected by GA.  My second view I call my 'Filtered View', which is the view I look at 99% of the time.  In the filtered view, I exclude company IPs, bot IPs, vendor IPs, etc.

To answer your question about access to each property and view, they can be set on any level from the admin menu under the user management option.